# Convert date and time to timestamp format java "2019-02-21T14:10:18.161+0000"

Tags: java, android, timestamp, simpledateformat

I need to convert this time and date to this timestamp format :
**2019/04/22 10:04:30** to **2019-02-21T14:10:18.161+0000**

this is my code, it's not working, I miss something, right?

```
String isoDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(isoDatePattern);

Date d = null;
try {
    d = simpleDateFormat.parse("2019/04/22 10:04:30");
} 
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(d);
Log.e("dateString ::::> ",dateString);
```

Comment: Your `isoDatePattern` is different from the actual input format you are trying to parse with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to parse the input with the output format. Untested:

```
String isoInputDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat simpleInputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(isoInputDatePattern);

String isoOutputDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat simpleOutputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(isoOutputDatePattern);

Date d = null;
try {
   d = simpleInputDateFormat.parse("2019/04/22 10:04:30");
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

String dateString = simpleOutputDateFormat.format(d);
Log.e("dateString ::::> ",dateString);
```

Comment: It's working, thank's @Christian.
my output : E/dateString ::::>: 2019-04-22T10:04:30.000+0100

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310. Use *java.time* classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given the date string you're trying to parse, you would need:

```
String datePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
```

For the pattern.

You probably should consider using Java 8 date/time though instead:

```
String str = "2019/04/22 10:04:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Comment: not sure I understand why.  There is no rule that all date formats must conform to ISO 8601 (maybe it's a best practice), but that's not the OP's requirements.

Comment: I see, I just pasted OP's code and didn't check the variable name.  Fixed.

Comment: @BasilBourque fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need two formats: the format of the date you have, to parse it, and the format of the date you want, to format it back.